# How do you make printing use default settings every time you print?

Tags: unity, printing, evince

I would like 'Print' to use default settings instead of settings used last time. If I used 2 on a side printing last time, I would not want it to remember that setting next time. Is it possible to change this behaviour? Specifically, I print mostly from evince.

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking the 'gear' shaped icon in the top right of the Ubuntu screen to get to the 'Settings' window, and choose 'System Settings'.
Click on 'Printers', which will show you the printers you have installed.
Right-click on the printer you wish to set up, and click on 'Properties'.
There, in the left pane, are the default settings from which you can choose.
Fingers crossed!

Answer (score 0):

For those interested in a way of printing from command line with "default" settings, make a script such as bellow. In my particular case, this is for pringing 1 inch margin, double sided document. Save in ~/bin as `printing.sh` and run with filename as command line argument `pringing.sh filename`. Personally I mostly use it with text files.

```
#!/bin/mksh
# Author:Serg
# Description: script to print 1 inch margin documents, double sided


lp $*  -d Deskjet_F4200 -o page-bottom=72 -o page-top=72 -o page-left=72 -o page-right=72  sides=two-sided-long-edge
```